# Read data from Firebase in Swift

Tags: json, swift, database, firebase

This is what my JSON file in FireBase looks like:

[image: JSON]

I am trying to look in Firebase tutorial in Firebase Web but it dosent work for me:

[image: Code image]

Comment: Best not to post code as an image and instead paste it into stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, this way one can easily tweak the code and I don’t have to write complete method again. And will be able to provide you complete answer with context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let value = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
                for (_,profile) in value {

          let name = profile["Name"] as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to dig one more level to get the properties you want. Your current dictionary is holding values under persons tree.

```
(value[“Manny”] as? [String:Any])?[“Name”] as? String
```

Comment: Hi,ive tried to do whats you ask for and dig one more level in JSON but its not help, now i have Persons->Names->["A","B","C"].... and my code is et refe = Database.database().reference().root.child("Persons").child("Names")
        refe.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value
            print (value)
            // ...
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

Comment: What output you are getting in this case??